# cocos 2dx getPosition() , always returns initial position instead of current position

Tags: cocos2d-x

I have a sprite with having an action through which, it moves towards right side.

```
 CCSprite *spaceShip1=CCSprite::create("ufo_1.png");
 spaceShip1->setPosition(ccp(visibleSize.width/8,visibleSize.height/2));
 this->addChild(spaceShip1, 3);
 CCMoveBy* moveleft1 = CCMoveBy::create(3, ccp(visibleSize.width, 0));
 spaceShip1->runAction(moveleft1);
```

I want to get the current visual position of sprite, as it is moving due to runAction, it should return its updated position.

I am using:

```
spaceShip1->getPosition();
```

and this position is utilizing here:

```
CCParticleSystemQuad* _spaceShip1 = new CCParticleSystemQuad();
_spaceShip1 = CCParticleSystemQuad::create("growingFlare.plist");
_spaceShip1->setPosition(spaceShip1->getPosition());
_spaceShip1->setAngle(180);
_spaceShip1->setScale(5);
_spaceShip1->stopSystem();
this->addChild(_spaceShip1, 4);
```

That particle effect must take place at the current position of spaceship, but it always took effect at initial position of spaceship.

I'm trying to get the current position of sprite. but it always returns the initial position instead of its current moving position.

**What I have to do to get its current position?**

Comment: Can you explain where have you done this spaceShip->getPosition() ?

Comment: position gets updated during that MoveBy action. Have you checked the getPosition in any update loop while the animation is happening ?

Comment: @sanchitgulati I have updated the question that where the getPosition() is used.

Answer (score 0):

```
float xPos = spaceShip->getPositionX();
float yPos = spaceShip->getPositionY();
CCLog("%f     %f", xPos, yPos);
```

Try this in the method where you want to get the current x,y position of the moving sprite. It won't get the initial position what you get now.

Comment: it always prints the initial position of spaceship even it is moving.

Answer (score 0):

That particle initialization happens during init(). Animation is not live then, hence will always give initial position.

You have 2 options.

1. In your update method. SetPosition() of your particle system every frame to the updated spaceship getPostion.
2. Make particle system as a child of spaceship. 
   In case of, "this->addChild()", do "_firstSpaceShip->addChild(_particleSystem)" and give it a initial x position like -10, so it always follow behind your spaceship.

Answer (score -1):

May be this will help you out

`CCParticleSystemQuad* _spaceShip1 = new CCParticleSystemQuad();
_spaceShip1 = CCParticleSystemQuad::create("growingFlare.plist");
_spaceShip1->setPosition(spaceShip1->getPositionX(), spaceShip1->getPositionY());`