# Why getPosition().y always returns value 0 in cocos2d-x?

Tags: cocos2d-x

I tried to use getPosition() function to get current y position
like Sprite->getPosition().y
But it does not work.. it always returns 0 only
I can't figure out why the result is always 0
If this function does not work, how can I get current y position of a sprite?

Comment: I have tried the solution presented in the link below, but it was not use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24730270/cocos-2dx-getposition-always-returns-initial-position-instead-of-current-pos

Comment: Post your code.. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

First You must confirm your Sprite position Y is not 0,
then show your code where use getPosition().y is 0;